# How to convert a UTF-8 string to URL compliant string in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, urllib2, urllib

I'm sure I'm not the first one to run into this problem. But after hours of debugging, Googling and StackOverflow-ing without finding an answer, I decided to post this question. So sorry in advance if I missed anything, but by now, I'm pretty confused.

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse a UTF-8 website. I'm using text from the website to build a URL to further crawl to. I'm running into some problems with non-English characters.

For example: the site contains the string `Originální formule` and I want to use it to build the URL: `http://blahblah.com/Originální-formule` or `http://blahblah.com/origin%C3%A1ln%C3%AD-formule`. The problem is, I'm getting `http://blahblah.com/Origin\xe1ln\xed-formule`, which produces an error. I tried to encode, decode and what-not, yet I still can't get the proper URL.

BTW, when I `print u'Origin\xe1ln\xed-formule'`, the string prints just fine. It just encoding that doesn't succeed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ... We don't know. What *are* you doing?

Comment: The question is, how to convert the string u'Origin\xe1ln\xed-formule' to something I can use with urllib2/urllib.urlopen()?

Comment: have you tried [the urlencode function](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib#urllib.urlencode)?

Comment: @l4mpi urlencode doesn't accept a string as a parameter. It's used to encode parameters into a parameters string. This is not my case. SanSS's answer is correct, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you are expecting you have to do the following things:

1. Decompose the url
2. Get the path part and encode it to utf-8
3. Quote the path
4. Join each part to get back a quoted URL

You can perform these with a combination of the following functions:

- `urlparse.urlparse` ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html))
- `urllib.quote` ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib))
- `urlparse.unparse` ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html))

The code will end up like this:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse
from urllib import quote
x = u'http://blahblah.com/Originální-formule'
parsed_url = list(urlparse(x.encode('utf-8')))
parsed_url[2] = quote(parsed_url[2])
urlunparse(parsed_url)
```

Result: `http://blahblah.com/Origin%C3%A1ln%C3%AD-formule`

Comment: I didn't need to split the url and join it again. But what I needed to do was indeed to encode it to utf-8 and then to quote it. Thanks!

Comment: You need to split it if you have non-ASCII characters in the hostname, as they need to be encoded using the Punycode algorithm (IDNA) rather than UTF-8+%-encode.